# JAX-RS Jersey JSON ObjectMapper configuration ignored

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jackson

I've the following code to change a property in Jackson. I'm annotating the classes with XMLRootElements and letting Jersey convert it to JSON, using jackson.

Classes are JAXB annotated.

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/json")
public class JacksonObjectMapper implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

     public JacksonObjectMapper() throws Exception {
        objectMapper.configure( DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    }

@Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
         return this.objectMapper;
    }
}
```

The configuration above, works as expected if I use Jackson outside jersey (i.e: using his own function), but If I use it inside a Jersey app, the configuration options are ignored.

Is there a way to instruct Jersey to use my class to serialize / deserialize from XML to JSON?

Comment: Is something missing from example? Specifically, are you constructing `ObjectMapper`, or expecting something to provide it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this class to your javax.ws.rs.core.Application's classes list:

```
application.addClass(JacksonObjectMapper.class)
```